# Joint Convergence implication

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Assume we have a stochastic process cadlag $X_{t}$ (which may be stochastically continuous if we need).  Let $t_{i}$ be an arbitrary fine grid of the time, with $t_{i}\rightarrow \infty$ as $i\rightarrow \infty$. Lets say, that $X_{t_i}\xrightarrow{d} W$  and  assume $Z_{t_i}\xrightarrow{P} Z$ for another random variable $Z$ and $Z_{t}$ a stochastic cadlag process. Assume it is fullfilled that the joint convergence in distribution is fullfilled
$$
(X_{t_i},Z_{t_i})\Rightarrow (W,Z)
$$
Can we conclude, that
$$
(X_t,Z_t)\Rightarrow (W,Z)
$$
holds, as $t\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first convergence holds for any sequence $(t_i)_{i\geq 0}$, then the second holds (by definition)

If your first convergence holds for a particular $t_i$, then the second does not hold in general. It may even not have a meaning.